# R - Creating a multiple column box plot with labeled outliers

Tags: r

I am trying to create a boxplot with labeled outliers. My data is in long form:

```
head(data.basic)
   STATE      variable  value
1    ALABAMA  FY_1998 0.363746457
2     ALASKA  FY_1998 0.632334359
3    ARIZONA  FY_1998 0.512511586
4   ARKANSAS  FY_1998 0.485002318
5 CALIFORNIA  FY_1998 0.696569322
6   COLORADO  FY_1998 0.351297291
```

The goal is to create a boxplot for each variable (ie "FY_1998" : "FY_2013"). This is simple with the default boxplot function but the result does not include labeled outliers. The Boxplot formula in the Car package is proving more challenging. I was able to create a boxplot for one year with the data in wide form with the following code:

```
Boxplot(Basic.Assistance[["FY_1998"]], labels=rownames(Basic.Assistance))
```

However, I was unable to expand this method to the other variables and, therefore, tried to use Boxplot with the long form data. Any help in either expanding the method above to include FY_1998 through FY_2013 or writing code for the same result with the long form code would be greatly appreciated.

I am new to R as well as this forum and apoligize for leaving out any necessary material. Just let me know if more code or information is necessary - thanks in advance.

```
summary(data.basic)
STATE             variable            value          
 Length:832         Length:832         Length:832        
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
> tail(data.basic)
        STATE variable       value
827      VIRGINIA  FY_2013 0.346652203
828    WASHINGTON  FY_2013 0.215769738
829 WEST_VIRGINIA  FY_2013 0.219831256
830     WISCONSIN  FY_2013 0.226368331
831       WYOMING  FY_2013 0.153766717
832 AVERAGE_STATE  FY_2013 0.235787342
```

Comment: You could perhaps report more records of your `data.basic` dataframe, including one or two more variables such as "FY_2013"?

Comment: I just added summary(data.basic) as well as tail(data.basic).

Answer (score 0):

%%%%% Shot 1: failed miserably
How about this:

```
data.basic <- read.table(head=TRUE, text="
        STATE variable       value
      ALABAMA  FY_1998 0.363746457
       ALASKA  FY_1998 0.632334359
      ARIZONA  FY_1998 0.512511586
     ARKANSAS  FY_1998 0.485002318
   CALIFORNIA  FY_1998 0.696569322
     COLORADO  FY_1998 0.351297291
     VIRGINIA  FY_2013 0.346652203
   WASHINGTON  FY_2013 0.215769738
WEST_VIRGINIA  FY_2013 0.219831256
    WISCONSIN  FY_2013 0.226368331
      WYOMING  FY_2013 0.153766717
AVERAGE_STATE  FY_2013 0.235787342")

rownames(data.basic) <- data.basic$STATE
Boxplot(value~variable, data=data.basic)
```

%%%% Shot 2: maybe more lucky this time?

```
library(dplyr)
library(car)
set.seed(4)
states <- c("ALABAMA","ALASKA","ARIZONA","ARKANSAS","CALIFORNIA","COLORADO","VIRGINIA","WASHINGTON")
data.basic <- data.frame(STATE=rep(states,2),
                         variable=rep(c("FY_1998","FY_2013"),each=length(states)),
                         value=rexp(2*length(states)))
## This does not work:    
##Boxplot(value~variable, labels=data.basic$STATE, data=data.basic)
yl <- range(data.basic$value)
vars <- levels(data.basic$variable)
npl <- length(vars)
lapply(1:npl, function(ii) {
    dat <- data.basic %>% filter(variable==vars[ii])
    rownames(dat) <- dat$STATE
    Boxplot(value~variable, data=dat, ylim=yl, add=(ii!=1))
})
```

Comment: I am sorry, I was unclear. FY_1998 and FY_2013 are the first and last variables. every year from FY_1998 through FY_2013 is a variable.

Comment: I could only use the two variables which you provided me. Have you tried my last two rows of code on the full long-form dataset?

Comment: Yes, I got it to label the outliers with the row numbers but it will not label the outliers with the state names since the row names repeat.

Comment: 'Boxplot(value~variable, data=data.basic1, label= rownames(data.basic1$STATE))
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  attempt to select less than one element'

Comment: Got that (perhaps).

Comment: Ah ok. What is the "%>%"?

Comment: `%>%` is dplyr's pipe operator (btw I modified the code to load the dplyr library). The line `dat <- data.basic %>% filter(variable==vars[ii])` is equivalent to `dat <- subset(data.basic, variable==vars[ii])`

Comment: It looks great. Thank you for the assistance.